# Spring Hibernate integration using java persistence API?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring3 and Hibernate4. I have below the configuration to work with spring and hibernate.

### pom dependency

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
```

### applicationContext.xml

```
<bean name="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.rsat.Employee</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</prop>
            <!-- Added to mask bean relational constraint validation error -->
            <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate Transaction manager for US data source -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

### SomeDao.java

```
@Repository
public class SomeDao implements ISomeDao{

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
      //DAO methods here

}
```

### Employee.java

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee{
    @Id
    Long id;
       @Column(name = "NAME")
    String userName;

    //setter and getters

}
```

Above configuration is working fine without any issues.

But now i am asked to use Hibernate JPA and use persistence.xml.

Could you please tell me which approach is recommended? Also how can i use Hibernate JPA ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA isn't realliy a substitute of Hibernate. JPA is a generic specification of ORM (Object Relational Mapping). As with the case with other sub-technologies in Java, once many vendors started to invent similar thing, the Java community tried to create a spec to standardize it. Latest version of Hibernate does implement the JPA spec (as well as EclipseLink / DataNucleus / .. to name the others).

The benefit of using Hibernate-over-JPA is your code complies with the standard. Hence if later down the track for whatever reason you decide to change the ORM vendor you can do so with minimal code refactoring (because other vendor would (should) comply to the standards too)

There are many tutorials out there on the net on how to use JPA/Hibernate with Spring. One helpful way when I first get started is to checkout the Spring Roo project -- which is a code generator tool which can built a ready-to-use Spring MVC / JPA / Hibernate code project. From there you can inspect the configuration and setups.

Comment: gerrytan, Thanks for your answer. so do you recommend using EntityManager instead of SessionFactory? Is Sessionfactory specific to Hibernate ? Thanks!

Comment: Correct, if you look at the full class name SessionFactory starts with org.hibernate, whereas all JPA classes starts with javax.persistence. Anything with org.hibernate is specific to Hibernate. I can't make any recommendation, you need to understand the pros/cons and decide. Some people stick to Hibernate to avoid having to learn yet another new stuff while others push through with JPA in case something better than Hibernate appears or they want to switch to other vendor easily. Personally I'd suck the pain and go with learning JPA. Programmers are bound to lifetime learning anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is a JPA implementation of JPA. 
So as long as you stick you the JPA standard and avoid hibernate specific you will be fine.
Start with replacing session factory definition with the JPA equivalent EntityManagerFactory

```
<bean id="emf"
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="puName" />
</bean>
```

If you will place the persistence.xml under /META-INF/ it should start working out of the box.
Your transactionManager should be adjust as well. Look at the documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa) 
@Enttity is already jpa compliant

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is one of the first ORM framework became the market leader. There is no JPA specification defined for the ORM solutions when Hibernate was introduced in the market. After seeing the advantage of Hibernate APIs, Java community has created a common specifications known as [JPA](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317) for all the problems in the persistence mechanism.

Hibernate provides JPA implementation that is known as Hibernate JPA. What is different is that JPA implementations must compliant with the specifications but vendor solutions would have their own APIs (some times that would provide added valued to your application). It is always recommended to use the standard API like JPA for the future good.

If you are looking for the integration approach, this article about [Hibernate and Spring Integration](http://www.javabeat.net/integrating-spring-framework-with-hibernate-orm-framework/) may help.

Answer (score 0):

> Could you please tell me which approach is recommended? Also how can i use Hibernate JPA ?

Because Hibernate is an implementation of JPA specification, if you want to use it you should only take care about configuration. You should not use it directly in DAO classes. In DAO classes you should use JPA only.

Following are steps to configure Hibernate:
1. persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <!-- value="create" to build a new database on each run; value="update" to modify an existing database; value="create-drop" means the same as "create" but also drops tables when Hibernate closes; value="validate" makes no changes to the database -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <!-- Uncomment the following two properties for JBoss only -->
            <!-- property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="false" /-->
            <!-- property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners" value="false" /-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

2. applicationContext.xml

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Now in DAO class:

```
@Repository
public class OrderDetailsNativeDaoImpl implements OrderDetailsDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<OrderDetailsResult> getOrderDetails(int orderId) {
        String queryString = "SELECT dt.id, 1 as version, dt.orderid as orderId, od.orderdate as orderDate, pd.name as productName, dt.unitprice as unitPrice, dt.quantity as quantity"
        + " FROM orders od INNER JOIN orderdetails dt ON od.id = dt.orderid"
        + " INNER JOIN products pd ON dt.productid = pd.id WHERE dt.orderid = :orderId";

        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString, OrderDetailsResult.class);
        query.setParameter("orderId", orderId);

        List<OrderDetailsResult> beanList = query.getResultList();

        return beanList;
    }
}
```